# Why is error displayed for the end function but the code does it's job perfetly fine, and how do i echo the class for the anchor tag in the php code

Tags: php, html

I have auto generated table where all the items are displayed, since there are over 150 items i've made a php code and sorted them in tables of 10 where you can navigate pages using anchor tags
But you can't see the current page and when I'm out of ideas how to display the current page, I have the class a.active in my css and i need a way to echo class if it matches the url
This is the code to get the page number url. Where i get displayed the error probably due to use of end, but it confuses me since the code works and displays what i want, exapmle "?page=4". So how do i bypass the error display

*EDIT: As someone mentioned i forgot to put the error, here it is:*

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ishouldbedoingmyhomeworkrn\admin\manage-idiots.php on
> line 20

```php
    // Program to display URL of current page.
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on')
        $link = "https";
    else $link = "http";
         $link .= "://";
         $link .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $link .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $getpage = end(explode("?", $link)); //the error is this line, my guess is the use of end
    $pagename = '?'. $getpage;
    echo $pagename;
```

Now how do i set a condition to echo the class name "active" to the anchor tag in php under an if condition

```php
   echo "<a class=\"<?php if($pagename=$x){echo 'active';}?>\" href='?page=$x'> $x </a>";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You forgot to tell us the error you are seeing, please edit your question and add that.  It is a little hard to understand exactly what you're asking (some care with punctuation and sentences would really help), but I can see a typo in your last line of code - you start with `echo` which means it is PHP, in which case you should not use `<?php ...`.  Do your `$pagename` test separately first, set a variable like `$active`, and then use it in your `echo`. Or if you want to get adventurous, try a ternary expression.

Comment: you have a bunch of lines which concatenate to make a var then you explode it for the last bit, if your simply looking for if `$_GET['page']` equals the current page then do `echo '<a '. ($_GET['page'] == $x ? 'class="active"' : '').' href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a>';`